# What is the academic reference of the implementation for Foam::anisotropicFilter?

Tags: openfoam

OpenFOAM (the latest versions at the time of writing) provides three types of test filter for large eddy simulation applications:

1. `simpleFilter`
2. `laplaceFilter`
3. `anisotropicFilter`

Considering there are various **anisotropic** filters proposed in the literature, could anyone tell us which reference was used in the code implementation of the `anisotropicFilter`, as such information is not available through the [code guide](https://www.openfoam.com/documentation/cpp-guide/html/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was kindly provided by [Henry Weller](https://cfd.direct/about/henry-weller/) in response to a [feature ticket](https://bugs.openfoam.org/view.php?id=2849):

> The anisotropic filter was not implemented with reference to any
>   literature.